# Custom Post Type error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this piece of code to pull out cars and the car details in a custom post type within wordpress.

```
<h1>Cars for Sale</h1>
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'carlistings', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ); ?>
<ul id="carsforsale">
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $cardetails = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cardetails', true );
            foreach( $cardetails as $cardetails ) { ?> <!-- Line # 13 -->
        <li class="pop"><span>
            <span class="thumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); } ?></a></span>
            <span class="title"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></span>
            <strong>Make</strong> <?php echo $cardetails['make'] ?><br />
            <strong>Model</strong> <?php echo $cardetails['model'] ?><br />
            <strong>Year</strong> <?php echo $cardetails['year'] ?><br />
            <strong>Color:</strong> <?php echo $cardetails['color'] ?><br />
            <strong>Price:</strong> <?php echo $cardetails['price'] ?><br />
        </span></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The problem I have is, that after 3 enteries I get this error message

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/styleaut/public_html/wp-content/themes/styleautosales/page-30.php on line 13

line 13 falls on this part of the code:

```
foreach( $cardetails as $cardetails ) {
```

Comment: this means that `$cardetails` is not an array or object

Comment: Could you please advise further? My PHP knowledge is awful!

Comment: please print your variable using print_r($cardetails) and paste your result here

Comment: Array ( [price] => £16,995 [year] => 2009 [make] => Ford [model] => Mustang GT Premium [color] => Vapor Silver [location] => UK )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add if statement before foreach like this:

```
<h1>Cars for Sale</h1>
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'carlistings', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ); ?>
<ul id="carsforsale">
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $cardetails = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cardetails', true );
            if($cardetails) {
            foreach( $cardetails as $cardetails ) { ?>
        <li class="pop"><span>
            <span class="thumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); } ?></a></span>
            <span class="title"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></span>
            <strong>Make</strong> <?php echo $cardetails['make'] ?><br />
            <strong>Model</strong> <?php echo $cardetails['model'] ?><br />
            <strong>Year</strong> <?php echo $cardetails['year'] ?><br />
            <strong>Color:</strong> <?php echo $cardetails['color'] ?><br />
            <strong>Price:</strong> <?php echo $cardetails['price'] ?><br />
        </span></li>
<?php } // end foreach
} // end if ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: This worked, if I missed a field in the backend, it would throw an error, now I added the IF statement and its fixed it! Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the way you're calling [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). By setting the last parameter to true, it will return the value in the first row of the post meta, which will always be a string. Try calling the function without that parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
foreach( $cardetails as $cardetails ) {
```

to

```
foreach( $cardetails as $value ) {
```

and you will need to change all $cardetails variables usage in the body of foreach to $value, f.e.:

```
$cardetails['make']
```

needs to be changed to:

```
$value['make']

$cardetails['model'] to $value['model']
```

and so on..

Comment: That is not correct. `$cardetails` is not getting overwritten in the context. Refer this snippet http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d572f8165aff0f22e253da4f1ddae7213b274a6